# override git config --system in .gitconfig user file ( git config --global )

Tags: git, git-config

I have that file in a system wide configuration (but it can also be included with `git config include.path="/path/to/defaultconfig"` I would like to reset some values previously setted.

In particular, the default config file contains `diff.external = git-diff-wrapper`, and I would like to deactivate it for some user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is a system wide config, each user can *override* a config value in his/her global and local settings.

But there is no easy way to "deactivate" a setting in a lower config file.
Even set it to `""` generally has unintended consequences. That [very topic was discussed in April 2010](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Local-unset-override-global-options-td4881111.html).

For instance, deactivating the `send-email` option:

> True, after thinking a bit about this using no value to unset is a horrible, horrible hack.
>   `git-send-email` should be corrected to not only check that there is value from config or command line option, but also that it is sane (i.e. non-empty, or simply true-ish if we say
>   that `smtpuser = "0"` is not something we need to worry about supporting).

That would be true for any setting: the [`diff.c#run_diff_cmd()`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/diff.c#L3005-L3045) function will attempt to run an external diff if [it has detected](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/diff.c#L200-L201) and `diff.external` value (even `""`).

```
if (!strcmp(var, "diff.external"))
  return git_config_string(&external_diff_cmd_cfg, var, value);
```

leads to:

```
if (pgm) {
  run_external_diff(pgm, name, other, one, two, xfrm_msg,
  complete_rewrite);
  return;
}
```

So there is no easy way to block a system wide diff external, except by making sure those users reference a different git system installation path (meaning a different system setting).