# What is the default location for included files when building a docker image?

Tags: build, docker, include, containers, dockerfile

```
derrend@laptop ~/topdir $ docker version
Client version: 1.7.1
Client API version: 1.19
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 786b29d
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.7.1
Server API version: 1.19
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): 786b29d
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64
```

---

```
derrend@laptop ~/topdir $ pwd; ls *
$HOME/topdir
Dockerfile

afolder:
afile
```

As I understand it, when I execute a `docker build` the `afolder` and its contents will be included inside my docker image but where will they be placed if I do not designate a location in the `Dockerfile`?

Comment: I have tried this as an experiment and then searched inside of the newly built image but have been unable to find the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those files are not part of the *built* (end-result) image.

They are part of the build *context* passed to the daemon [during the build process](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/), to be used by Dockerfile directives like [`ADD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add) or [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) or [`RUN`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run).

> A build’s context is the files located in the specified PATH *or URL*
>
> For example, run this command to use a directory called docker in the branch container:

```
$ docker build https://github.com/docker/rootfs.git#container:docker
```

This is managed by [`Context` and `ModifiableContext`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/e21d06a972b0edb44030db72b35e4882f05082e4/builder/builder.go#L29-L55).

Comment: Note to self: That was my **14000th answer** on Stack Overflow (in 87 months), less than 5 months after the [13000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31640408/6309). Before that, [12000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28412501/6309); [11000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25821796/6309), [10000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23909654/6309), [9000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20683667/6309), [8000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17569094/6309), [7000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14274272/6309), [6000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11644343/6309),...