# How to split every commit by file?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-rewrite-history

I know how to manually split a commit using `git rebase -i`, but how can I automatically split every commit in a branch by file?

For instance, commit `A` modified 3 files, f1, f2 and f3. After the split, there are 3 commits A-f1, A-f2 and A-f3.

I want to do this to make a major rewriting easier as I will only have to squash some small commits.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to split commits by file, because then you'll have many commits where one file changed its interface but its collaborators don't reflect that change. If you don't care about the detail, err on the side of squashing not splitting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### The Script

The following script splits `HEAD` by file:

```shell
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

SHA=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)

# Change to repo root directory
cd $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)

git reset HEAD^

git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $SHA | while read -r f; do
  git add "$f"
  GIT_EDITOR="echo '0a\n$SHA $f\n\n.\nw' | ed -s" git commit -c $SHA
done
```

The generated commit messages are of the form:

```
<original SHA> <file name>

<original commit message>
```

### Usage

The following assumes that you can run above script as `git-split`.

If you want to split all commits in a range by file, use it like this:

```
git rebase --interactive --exec git-split <branch>
```

If you want to split a single commit during an interactive rebase, use it like this:

```
p Commit to split
x git-split
```

Any improvements to the script are welcome.

Comment: Interesting script, more detailed than my answer. +1

Comment: @VonC Your answer gave a good outline of what to do and got me started.
All in all I would prefer a copy-paste friendly one-liner instead of my script, though :)

Comment: Great script, just the `GIT_EDITOR` line didn't work for me. I changed it to `git commit -m "$SHA: ${f}"` for a simpler commit message, and now the script works wonderfully =3

Comment: @Ancurio Glad you liked the script. Which OS are you on? Is `ed` installed (run `which ed` to check)?

Comment: @raphinesse yes `which ed` responds positively. I am on Fedora 31.

Comment: @Ancurio Hm. Maybe the `echo '0a\n$SHA $f\n\n.\nw'` isn't as portable as I thought. Could you try replacing that with `printf '0a\n$SHA $f\n\n.\nw\n'` (mind the extra `\n` at the end)?

Comment: @raphinesse didn't work either, but this time I got an "there was a problem with the editor 'nano'" message.

Comment: @Ancurio Strange. Why would it try to call nano? I'm out of ideas. But thanks for trying out my suggestions.

Comment: @raphinesse no idea. to me, the only important part was knowing which commit affected which file so I could properly bisect. Everything else was just fluff.

Comment: Great solution. The `GIT_EDITOR` line and sed are cool, but overkill: to prefix a line to the commit message, you can instead do `(printf "%s %s\n\n" "$SHA" "$f"; git show -s --format=%B "$SHA") | git commit -F -`.

Answer (score 2):

For every commit, you would need

- first to [list all files in that commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/424142/6309)

  ```
  git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r <SHA1>
  ```
- then for each file, [extract that file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/610315/6309)

  ```
  git show <SHA1>:/path/within/repo/to/file
  ```

Do that in a working tree of a dedicated branch, and for every file extracted, add and commit.

Then you can reset your current branch by that new one built commit-file by commit-file.

Comment: Note to self: That was my **16000th answer** on Stack Overflow (in 98 months), less than 6 months after the [15000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37539529/6309). Before that [14000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34327286/6309), [1300th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31640408/6309). [12000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28412501/6309); [1100th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25821796/6309), [10000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23909654/6309), [9000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20683667/6309), [8000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17569094/6309), ...