# Connecting one Github repository to several Aptana projects

Tags: git, github, repository, aptana

Is there a way to connect one Github repository to several different projects in Aptana? In other words, to have different directories in a single Github repository connected to different Aptana projects?

I need this ability since I'm a freelancer who works on many projects, and I don't wish to pay loads of $$$ to Github. This used to be possible with SVN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A GitHub repo in itself isn't connected to anything, it only contains a set of files.
If, amongst those files, you have several Aptana projects, you can use those once you have clone locally.

However, if you want to clone only a *part* of the GitHub repo in order to get only one of those projects, this isn't possible ([partial clones by filepath aren't supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2587244/6309))

If you want only *one* GitHub repo, then store your different Aptana project in **separate branches**.
You can then clone multiple times the same repo, and checkout a different branch depending on your project.
[Since git1.7.10+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9920956/6309), you can even [`git clone`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) just *one* branch out of your repo!

```
git clone --single-branch
```

> Clone only the history leading to the tip of a single branch, either specified by the `--branch` option or the primary branch remote's HEAD points at.
>   When creating a shallow clone with the `--depth` option, this is the default, unless `--no-single-branch` is given to fetch the histories near the tips of all branches.

But that may have limitations associated with shallow clone, ie:

> A shallow repository has a number of limitations (you cannot clone or fetch from it, nor push from nor into it), but is adequate if you are only interested in the recent history of a large project with a long history, and would want to send in fixes as patches.

Comment: As always, +1 is deserved here.

Comment: Note to self: And that, ladies and gents, was my **6000th** answer on Stack Overflow (in 46 months), 9 months after the [5000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7917396/6309). Before that: [4000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953561), [3000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074849), [2000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027976) and [1000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665252).