# Quantum Computers: can we start programming it?

Tags: quantum-computing

Although we'll have to wait at least two or three decades until we can see a practical QC, it seems that theoretical studies are improving dramatically (studies using the free QLC language are good examples). However, does that make us expect that big companies and corporations are building (maybe secretly)  ‘quantum software’: each seeking to get the leadership in this domain?

Comment: Outside of academia or possibly military/intelligence agencies I doubt it. It's still very much theoretical AFAIK

Comment: I *could* tell you, but we might get entangled.

Comment: I hear quantum computers are very bad at I/O.  Same reason Turing machines never caught on.

Comment: well, since the question is closed [so abruptly] it seems we cannot :)

Comment: @mlvljr: The question was closed because it has no answer.

Comment: Question is closed, but for what it's worth, I've described some relatively recent (2007-today) developments on the subject here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432922/significant-new-inventions-in-computing-since-1980/5161092#5161092